# Angular exercise with a few task

Tags: angular

I'm trying to solve an angular exercise with the following tasks:

/* MODIFY THE CODE TO ACCOMPLISH THE FOLLOWING

1. Enable the Band Name field if all the other fields are filled out
2. Modify the bandName() validator to only be valid if the following rules are met
   a) The band name must start with the first letter of of the First Name field
   b) The band name must contain the age
3. The background of Band Name must be the appropriate color which corresponds to the department
4. Modify the template to restrict age input to only a number
   */

I kinda got stuck on a very early stage, for some reason i don't get there is no communication at all between the logic and the view component since i'm not able to console log any of the form group attributes. this is the first time i'm working with the form builder group and i'm not really familiar with it. Thanks for everyone. this is my code:

Script:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  ValidatorFn,
  AbstractControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz',
  templateUrl: './quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz.component.css']
})
export class QuizComponent implements OnInit {

  colorAssociation = {
    Technology: 'lightblue',
    Design: 'lightgreen',
    Education: 'purple'
  };

  form: FormGroup;
  bandNameForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  getBackgroundColor() {
    let color = '';
    if (this.form) {
      let dept = this.form.value.department;
      if (dept) {
        color=this.colorAssociation[dept];
      }
    }
    return color;
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      age: ['', Validators.required],
      department: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.bandNameForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      bandName: ['', bandName(this.form)],
    });
    this.form.setValidators(areTheFieldsFilledOut(this.bandNameForm,this.form));
    this.bandNameForm.controls.bandName.disable();
  }


}

export function bandName(form: FormGroup): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    let error = 'Invalid';
    let value = control.value;
    let firstLetter = '';
    let age;
    if (form) {
      let firstName = form.value.firstName;
      age = form.value.age;
      console.log(value);

      if (firstName) {
        firstLetter = firstName[0];
      }
      if (value.indexOf(firstLetter)===0 && value.includes(age)) {
        error=null;
      }
    }
    // fill out the rest of the validator logic
    return error ? { error: { value: error } } : null;
  };
}


export function areTheFieldsFilledOut(bandNameForm: FormGroup, form:FormGroup): ValidatorFn {
  return (control:AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    let error = 'Invalid';
    
    if (
      !(form.value.age === '') &&
      !(form.value.department === '') &&
      !(form.value.firstname === '')
    ) {
      bandNameForm.controls.bandName.enable();
    }
    return error ? { error: { value: error } } : null;
  };


}
```

Template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
        
    <label for="firstName">First Name
        <input type="text"
        formControlName="firstName"
        >
    </label>
    <label for="age">age
        <input type="number"
        formControlName="age"
        >
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <h4>Department:</h4>
    <br><br>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input formControlName="department" value="technology" type="radio">
            <span>Technology</span>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input formControlName="department" value="education" type="radio" />
            <span>Education</span>
        </label>
    </p>
     <p>
        <label>
            <input formControlName="department" value="design" type="radio"  />
            <span>Design</span>
        </label>
    </p>
    <br><br>

    <form [formGroup]="bandNameForm">
        <label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="band">
            <span>Band Name</span>
        </label>

    </form>
    <br><br>
        
    <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Apart from voting you can also mark one right / best answer. Thank you, take care and have fun on SO.

Answer (score 1):

### Minor Mistake

All I had to change was the formControlName for the bandNameForm in the template (band -> bandName). It has to match the name of the FormControl in the FormGroup.

Template:

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="bandName" />
```

### Disabling Submit

Template:

```html
[disabled]="!bandNameForm.valid"
```

### Dynamic Background Color

Template:

```
[ngStyle]="getBGC()"
```

Script:

```js
getBGC() {
    const dep = this.form.get('department').value
    return { 'backgroundColor' : this.colorAssociation[dep] }
}
```

** I also changed the object holding the color values to not start with a capital letter (to match the names in the FormGroup).*

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhvlw6?file=src/app/app.component.html) that prints the values when pressing submit. I'll leave the actual exercise to you until you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I figured thus one out i only have two more problems left. 1. i'm trying to disable the submit button until all the criterias are met, and I can't quite figure how. I tried this line: ` <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" [disabled]="!bandName.valid">Submit</button>` but it doesn't work. The second is extracting the right color from the object. for some reason the line doesn't work: `color=this.colorAssociation[dept]`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try: `[disabled]="!bandNameForm.valid"`and for the color try the `[ngStyle]` directive. Let me know if you can't find it on your own and I'll give the solution. But I suggest you try first.

Comment: im familiar with ngStyle. My only problem is how to make this function to return the right color: `  getBackgroundColor() {
    let color='';
    if (this.form) {
      const dept = findIndex(this.form.value.department);
      if (dept) {
        
        color=this.colorAssociation[dept];
      }
    }
    return color;
  }` if you can help me with that it will be great!

Comment: btw the other correction worked so thanks!

Comment: it currently gives me this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ Technology: string; Design: string; Education: string; }'.ts(7053) but when i do this for example: this.colorAssociation.Technology - It gives me the right color. I can't figure out why

Comment: also, I tried `this.colorAssociation.dept` and it throws an error as well

Comment: I updated the answer and the Stackblitz, cheers.

Comment: Thank you! btw eventually the problem was that typescript expected me to define the color association object in the following way: `colorAssociation: {[key: string]: any }` but you really helped me a lot !!